# How to implement user-exit 'EXIT_SAPLIQS0_017' for fields BEQUI and BTPLN?

Tags: abap, netweaver

After updating a notification, I want to insert both an affected equipment (BEQUI) and functional location (BTPLN) in table VIQMEL. I read some topics that mentioned user exit EXIT_SAPLIQS0_017. However, I never saw an implementation of it and mine doesn't work.

This is what have tried so far; I know it is very basic but I'm very inexperienced with user exits.

```
  data: ls_notif  type viqmel.
  data: lt_qmfe   type table of wqmfe.
  data: lt_qmur   type table of wqmur.
  data: lt_qmma   type table of wqmma.
  data: lt_qmsm   type table of wqmsm.

  select single * from viqmel into @data(ls_viqmel) where qmnum eq '000010000719'.
  select single * from tq80 into @data(ls_tq80) where qmart eq @ls_viqmel-qmart.

  ls_viqmel-bequi = '1000069'.
  ls_viqmel-btpln = '1010'.

  call function 'EXIT_SAPLIQS0_017'
    exporting
      i_viqmel = ls_viqmel
      i_tq80   = ls_tq80
    importing
      e_viqmel = ls_notif
    tables
      t_viqmfe = lt_qmfe
      t_viqmur = lt_qmur
      t_viqmma = lt_qmma
      t_viqmsm = lt_qmsm.
```

I get the viqmel structure back, but nothing seems to have changed when I check the VIQMEL table. Any ideas?

Comment: `EXIT_*_###` are function modules that are the user exits themselves, which you may implement. You must not call them. You implement these user exits via the transaction code `CMOD` (create a project, assign the enhancement, go to the function module and add code for the empty `INCLUDE` source unit). In your case, it's the enhancement `QQMA0025` and the include `ZXWOCU21`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it correctly noted by Sandra, you do not call exits directly but rather implement them.

1. Create `ZXWOCU21` include where just write only these two lines of code

   ```
   e_viqmel-bequi = '1000069'.
   e_viqmel-btpln = '1010'.
   ```

You shouldn't fill parameters manually (like `tq80`), they are pre-populated by system by default.

2. Create the project in CMOD tcode (if not exists) for the enhancement component `QQMA0025` which contains your user-exit and activate it. Here is the manual

[Create Enhancement Project for SAP User Exit Function using CMOD in ABAP](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/create-cmod-enhancement-project-for-user-exit-function.aspx)

Comment: Is QQMA0014 the corresponding enhancement for BAPI_ALM_NOTIF_DATA_MODIFY?

Comment: Usually BAPIs are separate modules that are not a part of enhancements, and they should be called manually unlike exits. Naming pattern for exits is `EXIT_XXXXXX`. You can check which modules are included in certain exit in SMOD tcode, enter enhancement name and select components

Comment: Okay, QQMA0025 is triggered by IW21 and 'BAPI_ALM_NOTIF_CREATE'. But QQMA0014 is only triggered by IW22 and not by 'BAPI_ALM_NOTIF_DATA_MODIFY. Any idea why that is or how I can work around it?

Comment: `Any idea why` why is a rhetorical question and can be answered only by SAP, it's their standard code. How you can work around it? No way. You cannot do this by exit, their call points are fixed and cannot be changed, however you can modify `BAPI_ALM_NOTIF_DATA_MODIFY` and place your custom code from exit into [explicit/implicit enhancement](https://help.sap.com/viewer/46a2cfc13d25463b8b9a3d2a3c3ba0d9/7.5.9/en-US/a047e94086087e7fe10000000a1550b0.html), for example in line 38 of this BAPI

Answer (score 1):

You may check the Z "include file" from `EXIT_SAPLIQS0_017`. If someone already implemented it (or assigned it to his(her), it is better to make a comment line why you add and where you put your logic.

From ABAP side, basically you implement this Z include in your package. When you double click it, and GUI (or Eclipse) will navigate it or give you a popup (will you create it ?)

How to find is simple, you can use `cmod` or `smod` as standard, but as you know already the exit name, try transaction code `SE37`. Fill out `EXIT_SAPLIQS0_017` and check the `INCLUDE z...` inside.